# Decomposing an optimisation problem

Tags: optimization

Take the following optimisation problem
$$
(*) \hspace{1cm} h(u_1,u_2,u_3)\equiv \min_{p_1,p_2,p_3} \sum_{j=1}^3(f(u_j,p_j))^2\\
\text{s.t. } g(u_j,p_j)\leq b_j \text{ }\forall j \in \{1,2,3\}\\
$$
where

- $u_j$, is an $m$-dimensional vector of real numbers, known by the researcher, for each $j\in \{1,2,3\}$.
- $p_j$ is an $n$-dimensional vector of real numbers, unknown by the researcher, for each $j\in \{1,2,3\}$.
- $b_j$ is a $k$-dimensional vector of real numbers, known by the researcher, for each $j\in \{1,2,3\}$.
- $f:(u_j, p_j)\in \mathbb{R}^m\times  \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto f(u_j, p_j)\in \mathbb{R}$ is a function, known by the researcher, for each $j\in \{1,2,3\}$.
- $g:(u_j, p_j)\in \mathbb{R}^m\times  \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto g(u_j, p_j)\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is a function, known by the researcher, for each $j\in \{1,2,3\}$.

Suppose we decompose problem $(*)$ in three optimisation problems indexed by $j\in \{1,2,3\}$:
$$
h_j(u_j)\equiv \min_{p_j} (f(u_j,p_j))^2\\
\text{s.t. } g(u_j,p_j)\leq b_j\\
$$
**Question:** Assume that problem $(*)$ is feasible. Is it true that
$$
h(u_1,u_2,u_3)=\sum_{j=1}^3 h(u_j)
$$
?

Comment: You should be able to prove it by writing the optimality conditions of the original problem and group them by same $j$.

Comment: Yes. The problem is completely separable in $p_j$.